# Convert array of object to array of arrays that contains objects with same value using JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to convert array of objects to array of array that contains objects with same value of **detect** property.

And different value of **detect** property would be a boundary for index of converted array.

```
const arr = [
  {fruit: "apple", detect: 0},
  {fruit: "orange", detect: 1},
  {fruit: "grape", detect: 1},
  {fruit: "banana", detect: 1},
  {fruit: "mango", detect: 0},
  {fruit: "strawberry", detect: 0},
  {fruit: "kiwi", detect: 1},
  {fruit: "melon", detect: 1},
  {fruit: "peach", detect: 0},
  {fruit: "blueberry", detect: 0},
  {fruit: "plum", detect: 1},
];
```

variable arr has the array of objects that has **date** and **detect** properties and value.

And I want to change this data to array of array that has same value but indexed by **detect** value 0.

```
 const convertedArr = [
  [
    {fruit: "orange", detect: 1},
    {fruit: "grape", detect: 1},
    {fruit: "banana", detect: 1},
  ],
  [
    {fruit: "kiwi", detect: 1},
    {fruit: "melon", detect: 1},
  ],
  [
    {fruit: "plum", detect: 1},
  ]
];
```

As you can see **fruit** value **orange** is the first property has **detect** value 1 and first index of convertedArr is made of **orange** to **banana** which is before **mango** property that has **detect** value 0.

And second index starts after **strawberry** index which is **kiwi** to **melon** property before **peach**.

I think this problem can be solved using **while** with other loop method but it is bit hard to wrap my head around using it.

Comment: What you've tried so far ? can you please post the code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Array.reduce`.

```js
const arr = [
  {fruit: "apple", detect: 0},
  {fruit: "orange", detect: 1},
  {fruit: "grape", detect: 1},
  {fruit: "banana", detect: 1},
  {fruit: "mango", detect: 0},
  {fruit: "strawberry", detect: 0},
  {fruit: "kiwi", detect: 1},
  {fruit: "melon", detect: 1},
  {fruit: "peach", detect: 0},
  {fruit: "blueberry", detect: 0},
  {fruit: "plum", detect: 1},
  {fruit: "foo", detect: 0},
  {fruit: "bar", detect: 0},
];


let currentSet = [];

let converted = arr.reduce((a, c) => {
  
  if (c.detect)
    currentSet.push(c)
  else {
  
    if (currentSet.length){
      a.push(currentSet)  
      currentSet = [];
     }
  }
  
  return a;
  
}, []);


if (currentSet.length)
  converted.push(currentSet);
console.log(converted);
```

Comment: If the last fruit in `arr` is `detect:0` you'll get an extra empty `[]` at the end of the `converted` array, which may not be what you want.

Comment: Yeah so I added extra condition after currentSet.length

Comment: ;-) that slightly improved it but if there are *multiple* `detect:0` objects at the end you will still get an empty array at the end.

Comment: Not really. The last condition can prevent that all.

Comment: @Charlie yeap I did the test and it is working fine

Answer (score 2):

You can use two array's one to keep track of final result other to keep track of continuous values that have detect 1.

- Loop through array if detect is zero and length of temp is greater than 0 add value to final
- Else add value to temp to accumulate continuous detect 1
- At end check if there are any element left in temp after loop add it to final

```js
const arr = [{fruit: "apple", detect: 0},{fruit: "orange", detect: 1},{fruit: "grape", detect: 1},{fruit: "banana", detect: 1},{fruit: "mango", detect: 0},{fruit: "strawberry", detect: 0},{fruit: "kiwi", detect: 1},{fruit: "melon", detect: 1},{fruit: "peach", detect: 0},{fruit: "blueberry", detect: 0},{fruit: "plum", detect: 1},];

let final = []
let temp = []

for (let element of arr) {

  // add value to final array when detect is 0 and temp.length > 0

  if ( element.detect === 0 ) {
    if ( temp.length ) {
      final.push(temp)
    }
    temp = []
  } else {
    temp.push(element)
  }
}

// to handle an edge case where we have detect 1 at end of array

if (temp.length) {
  final.push(temp)
}

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 0):

***Working Code !!***

```js
const arr = [{fruit: "apple", detect: 0},{fruit: "orange", detect: 1},{fruit: "grape", detect: 1},{fruit: "banana", detect: 1},{fruit: "mango", detect: 0},{fruit: "strawberry", detect: 0},{fruit: "kiwi", detect: 1},{fruit: "melon", detect: 1},{fruit: "peach", detect: 0},{fruit: "blueberry", detect: 0},{fruit: "plum", detect: 1},];
let res = [[]];
arr.map(o => {
   if(o.detect) {
     res[res.length-1].push(o);
   } else {
     if(res[res.length-1].length) res = [...res, []];
   }
});
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it:

```js
const arr = [{fruit: "apple", detect: 0},{fruit: "orange", detect: 1},{fruit: "grape", detect: 1},{fruit: "banana", detect: 1},{fruit: "mango", detect: 0},{fruit: "strawberry", detect: 0},{fruit: "kiwi", detect: 1},{fruit: "melon", detect: 1},{fruit: "peach", detect: 0},{fruit: "blueberry", detect: 0},{fruit: "plum", detect: 1},{fruit: "goji", detect: 0},{fruit: "pineapple", detect: 0}];

let res=arr.reduce((a,c,i)=>{
  if (c.detect) {
   if(!a.flag) a.flag=a.push([]);
   a[a.length-1].push(c);
  } 
  else a.flag=0;
  return a;   
}, [] );
console.log(res);
```

I changed the code to reliably avoid an empty array at the end.

Comment: Sorry for the repetition @Solanki, we seem to have had the same idea, only I was a bit slower. :D

Comment: HaHa.. It's OK, :)

Answer (score 0):

You could push the values you want to keep to a new multidimensional array by iterating over the original array using .forEach:

```js
let arr2 = [[]];
let i = 0;
arr.forEach(obj => {
  if (obj.detect == 1) {
    arr2[i].push(obj);
  } else {
    if(!arr2[i].length == 0){
      i++;
      arr2.push([]);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arrCh = [
    {fruit: "apple", detect: 0},
    {fruit: "orange", detect: 1},
    {fruit: "grape", detect: 1},
    {fruit: "banana", detect: 1},
    {fruit: "mango", detect: 0},
    {fruit: "strawberry", detect: 0},
    {fruit: "kiwi", detect: 1},
    {fruit: "melon", detect: 1},
    {fruit: "peach", detect: 0},
    {fruit: "blueberry", detect: 0},
    {fruit: "plum", detect: 1},
    {fruit: "foo", detect: 0},
    {fruit: "bar", detect: 0},
  ];



const newArrs = arrCh.filter((item)=> {
      return item.detect > 0;
})
let finishArray = [];
newArrs.map(item => {
    let arrNew = [];
    arrNew.push(item)
    finishArray.push(arrNew)
})
console.log(finishArray)
```